# What's making this program slow to process? (C++)

Tags: c++, performance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector< int > number;
    bool numbersAreCorrect = false;

    int input;

    while( cin >> input )
        number.push_back( input );

    vector< int > unique_number( number.size(), 0 );
    vector< int > repeated( number.size(), 1 );

    for( int i = 0; i < number.size(); i++ )
    {
        for( int j = i + 1; j < number.size() + 1; j++ )
        {
            if( number[ i ] != 0 && number[ i ] == number[ j ] )
            {
                repeated[ i ]++;
                unique_number[ i ] = number[ i ];
            }
            else
                unique_number[ i ] = number[ i ];

            if( j == number.size() )
            {
                for( int z = 0; z < number.size(); z++ )
                {   
                    if( number[ z ] == unique_number[ i ] )
                        number[ z ] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

    } 

    for( int i = 0; i < number.size(); i++ )
    {
        if( ( unique_number[ i ] != 0 && repeated[ i ] == 1 ) || ( unique_number[ i ] != 0 && repeated[ i ] % 2 != 0 ) )
        {   
            numbersAreCorrect = false;
            cout << unique_number[ i ] << endl;
            break;
        }

        else if( repeated[ i ] == 1 )
            numbersAreCorrect = true;

        else if( repeated[ i ] % 2 != 0 )
        {
            numbersAreCorrect = false;
            cout << repeated[ i ] << endl;
            break;
        }
        else if( repeated[ i ] % 2 == 0 )
            numbersAreCorrect = true;   
    }

    if( numbersAreCorrect == true )
        cout << "0" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This program gets positive integers from user, checks if an integer is repeated 2k( even) times or 2k+1(odd) times. if latter is true, it prints the integer , else it prints 0; I used 20000 inputs and it takes more than 10 seconds to evaluate.. I need to know how to make it process faster.
for example this input results in "0" : 1 2 2 1
and this results in "3" : 1 2 2 1 3

Comment: Take out the calls to `std::cout`.

Comment: If I understand your goal, you want to state whether each element is a unique or repeated entry, correct?  In that case, you are looping 20,000 * 20,000 times to get that ... which is why it is taking so long.  It can be done much faster using a map.  Also, when you print it, you are flushing the buffer (calling `cout << endl`) each time, which will greatly slow down your output.

Comment: Yes you're right about my goal. however this is an assignment and I can't use map.

Comment: One of the best ways to optimize this sort of search is to sort first, and then just iterate once over the list of integers comparing adjacent values. This assumes that you are allowed to change the order of the input, which may or may not be allowed in your assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about you first sort the thing.
Then you only need to do a single for loop instead of two because to find all the repetitions you just count consecutive occurrences.

Failing that use a set or map. Again you'll drop to O(NlogN) instead of O(N^2).

Comment: I solved the problem using "sort( number.begin(), number.end() )" from <algorithm> library. processed 20000 inputs with 1 for loop in 208 ms. thanks.